# Get the length of matched term in Solr results

Tags: solr

My solr index contains documents like

`{'term': 'abc corp'},
 {'term': 'new software'},
 {'term': 'abc      corp and ltd'},
 {'term': 'abc industry'}`

I am searching for documents using following query `term:abc\ co*`. Is there any way by which I can get the length of matched term. For example for the above search query the documents should be returned along with the length of matched terms as `{'term': 'abc corp', 'length': 6}, {'term': 'abc      corp and ltd', 'length': 11}`.

Comment: I think this you have to do it once you get the response or while indexing you can pass the length for the field

Comment: Yes that I can definitely do, but I was wondering if Solr provides some inbuilt mechanism for this

Answer (score 0):

The only built-in way (that I know) of handling it is to use a [FieldLengthUpdateProcessor](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldLengthUpdateProcessorFactory.html) as part of [the update chain for one of your fields](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html) when indexing. The processor will replace the content sent to the field with an integer representing the length of the field instead, so by using a `copyField` directive you can index the lengthof the same string to a separate field.

I did create a function query that returns the length of the given field, but it hasn't received any attention or been merged into any version of Solr - see [SOLR-9715 - Add function for string length](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9715)